# 64GB SD card shown as 2TB after inserted to Samsung Galaxy S9+

Tags: sd-card, data-recovery

I installed a 64GB memory card in a Samsung Galaxy S9+ and copied about 30GB of data to it. A couple of days later, the phone shows a notification saying "Can't open SD card for writing" or something like that. When the card is in the phone, it shows that it has around 30GB used. I can even see the photos in the gallery app but can't read or write to it.

I inserted the SD card into a Linux machine, ran `df -h`, and it says it exists but it doesn't have a partition. I then set up a Windows 10 VM and opened it. In it, it says "There is something wrong with this drive, do you want to format it?" (I know sometimes it says "scan and fix", but now it didn't and I don't know why). I tried with Autopsy which also sees it as 2TB and I don't have enough storage space to try and pull some data out of it.

I really need to pull that data, can anyone help? Or at least point to some data recovery tools (preferably for Linux)?

One more question: would `dd_rescue -A -d -D -b 512 /dev/sdX /dev/sdX` work? I don't want to try unless sure because the card and the data are not mine and I don't want to lose any of it.

Comment: What you describe would be typical for an forged sd-card: the card claims to be of size xGB but physically it only have a few GB of flash. Once you have stored more data to it as it has physical flash file-system goes defect. But the card is pretty small with only 64GB this makes it unlikely that it is forged. Where have you bought the card, are you sure it is genuine? Alternatively the card may be simply defect.

Comment: I've used Recuva from piriform.com for windows in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like corrupt MBR to me.
Do a little research on data recovery I found a how to geek article pointing towards ZAR, only on windows though. Hope this helps.

Article:https://www.howtogeek.com/232931/how-to-recover-images-off-a-corrupted-sd-card/

ZAR download: https://www.z-a-recovery.com/download.aspx